# how can I prove that set is closed in the usual topology?

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove that the set $\{(x,1/x) : x>0\}$ is closed in the usual topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$? Also is it closed in Niemytzki plane?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515953/euclidean-spaces This is the preimage of $1$ under the multiplication on $[0,\infty)\times\Bbb R$, so it is closed there, and thus also in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Since the Niemytzki topology is finer than the Euclidean, this set must also be closed in that one.

Comment: @StefanH IMHO this is a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{(x,1/x):x>0\}$ is the preimage of $1$ under the multiplication on $[0,∞)×\Bbb R$ which maps $(x,y)$ to its product $xy$, so it is closed in $[0,∞)×\Bbb R$, and thus also in $\Bbb R^2$.

The Niemytzki plane $\Bbb R\times [0,\infty)$ has a finer topology than the Euclidean topology, hence the set is also closed in Niemytzky plane.